# Datepicker UI Set defaultDate using $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have 2 inputs bound with  JqueryUI datepicker.

```
<div>Start Date <input id="startdate" type="text" class="DP" data-Dformat='2010-01-01'  ></div>
<div>End Date <input id="enddate" type="text" class="DP" data-Dformat='2010-01-27'  ></div>
```

Here is my script :

```
// INIT Date Picker 
  $('.DP').datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonText: "Date",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  });
  // Setter     
  $('.DP').datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", $(this).attr("data-dformat") );
```

I want datepicker when clicked to set the default display date to the value of the data attribute 'dformat' using $(this) to grab the data, but it doesn't work - it just displays the current date.

if I replace the 'setter' with

```
// Setter       
$('.DP').datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", '2010-01-01'  );
```

it all works as expected, Why can I get the data using $(this) ?

Any help much appreciated ! , thanks

Comment: Try using: `$('.DP').each(function(){ $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', '2010-01-01'); });`

Comment: ahem... Notice the uppercase D in `$(this).attr("data-Dformat")`... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Executing a statement such as `$('.DP').datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", '2010-01-01'  );` won't change the context. `this` will refer to whatever context in which the function was being executing.

You can achieve what you're trying to do by doing something like:

```
$('.DP').each(function(i,elm){
  $(this).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", $(this).attr("data-dformat")  );
});
```

Note that now we're executing it *inside* a different function where the context is the current element being iterated.

Also, you can't have HTML attributes with capital letters so `data-Dformat='2010-01-01'` should be `data-dformat='2010-01-01'`.

The common naming convention for class names is lowercase as well.